How to send an early response with Hono and continue executing
I am migrating a Google Cloud function to a Bun/Hono backend. My function is called from a sveltekit API endpoint and currently allows me an early response and continue to proceed with the rest of the code.
Google Cloud function:
export const create_backup = v2.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {    
      const { id: backupId } = ...

      // Early response to the client, as Sveltekit expects a response within 15 seconds. The backup will continue in the background, and we'll get notified
      response.status(HttpStatusCode.Accepted).json({
        status: 'In progress',
        data: { backupId },
      });

      // Continue to work
...
);

In Hono, I tried to simply use c.json without returning the statement, but it doesn't work:
 c.json(
      {
        status: 'In progress',
        data: { backupId },
      },
      HttpStatusCode.Accepted
    );

// above never sends anything back to the client
// ... continue

